Is this a bad siding install or normal for Hardie paneling?
My siding contractor seems to be doing subpar work and says this is all within spec. Are floating panels like shown below really acceptable?






What did you ask for? What is specified in the contract?

We asked for new siding. The contract states that it is installed to the manufacturer's specifications.

This can be fixed with some bondo and a steady hand. Hold back on the final payment to ensure this gets done (either by the contractor or someone you find to fix their work).

There's a lot here I don't like, but this question is entirely opinion-based or a contractual issue. Please see the [help] and take the [tour].

In the first picture, the contractor was being lazy. He should have removed the faucet handle and drilled a hole and fit the siding over the faucet. The second picture just looks like a covered up mistake. The third picture is too close to really determine a better way but the conduits through the wall make it tough. Either way, the edges should have been sanded smooth and fitted better. Fourth picture: I wouldn't expect the contractor to disconnect wires or tubling to go through a drilled hole, but the soluion they did was really sloppy and could have been done to look a lot better. In last picture, I wouldn't expect them to disconnect the pipe to go through a hole but they could have done a lot neater and narrower. They could have done the faucet by just drilling a hole.
A lot would depend on what was specified in the contract.
